Not Getting Params in next js 14
Just started learning next js and ran into this problem. When I click on view profile i get a not found page and not the desired userDetailsPage. Not getting the params.
My folder structure is like this
app/
    blog/
        page.tsx
        [slug]/
                page.tsx
                [userId]/
                        page.tsx

            

The code for the blog/page.tsx is
const BlogPage = async () => {
  const posts = await getData();
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-7 ">
      {posts.map((post: Posts) => (
        <div
          key={post.id}
          className="bg-slate-500 text-white p-7 flex flex-col justify-between items-center gap-4"
        >
          <h1>{post.title}</h1>
          <Link
            className="bg-yellow-500 text-white p-3 rounded-md"
            href={`/blog/${post.id}`}
          >
            Read More..
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default BlogPage;

The code for [slug]/page.tsx is
const SinglePostPage = async ({ params }: SinglePostPageProps) => {
  const post = await getSinglePost(params.slug);
  const user = await getUser(post.userId);

  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-500 p-7">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold py-4">{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
      <div>By {user.name}</div>
      <Link href={`/user/${user.id}`}>View Profile</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SinglePostPage;

And the code for [userId]/page.tsx is
import React from "react";

const UserDetails = ({ params }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>User Id: {params.userId}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserDetails;


If you're getting a page not found, it probably isn't you not getting the params but instead not reaching the route you think you're reaching. What is the path of the URL you're trying to access?

I am trying to reach /user/${user.id}. You can see it in the code snippet where I have specified the Link tag's href to that

My bad, didn't see that. However, if the file structure you provided is accurate, wouldn't the path be blog/$slug/$userId? Where did the /user/ bit come from in your URL if there is no user folder inside app?

Yeah..solved it..Created a user route in the root directory and then It was accessible. Thank You
